# Woocommerce Products: Ajax Pagination reloading page issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

`Wordpress Version 6.2.2` `Woocommerce Version 7.8.2` `Permalinks set to /%postname%/` `Product Permalinks set to /produkt/` `Theme: TwentyTwentyOne`

How can I prevent the whole page to refresh each time i use the pagination? Everything works fine, except the fact that each time i click a pagination link, the whole page refreshes. The url is updated like

h t t p s : / / w e b s i t e . c o m / ? p a g e d = 1

h t t p s: / / w e b s i t e . c o m / ? p a g e d = 2

h t t p s: / / w e b s i t e . c o m / ? p a g e d = 3

which is also fine.

Here is the code:

functions.php:

```
// Enqueue scripts and localize variables for AJAX pagination
function enqueue_ajax_pagination_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-pagination-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/custom-ajax.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

// Localize variables to be used in the AJAX script
wp_localize_script('ajax-pagination-script', 'twentytwentyone_ajax_object', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),));} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_pagination_scripts'); 

// Callback function for AJAX pagination
function load_products_ajax_callback() {
$page = max(1, (int)$_POST['page']); // Ensure the current page is at least 1

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 22,
    'paged' => $page,
    'orderby' => 'title', // Sort by product name
    'order' => 'ASC',    // Order in ascending (A to Z) 
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);

ob_start(); // Start output buffering

if ($products->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="table-2255"><div class="table-thead-2255"><div class="table-tr-2255"></div></div><div class="table-tbody-2255">';

    while ($products->have_posts()) {
        $products->the_post();
        global $product;

        // Get the product data
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
        $product_permalink = get_permalink();

        // Output the product details

        echo '<div class="table-tr-2255">';
        echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entryImage"><img src="' . $product_image[0] . '" alt="' . $product_name . '"></div>';
        echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entryName"><h2 class="c1"><a class="c1" href="' . $product_permalink . '">' . $product_name . '</a></h2></div>';

        // Additional product attributes

        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        if ($attributes && !empty($attributes)) { // Add a check for $attributes
            $counter = 1;
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($attribute->get_name());
                $attribute_value = array();

                // Get attribute options as labels
                $options = $attribute->get_terms();
                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $attribute_value[] = $option->name;
                }

                $css_class = 'entry' . $counter;

                echo '<div class="table-td-2255 ' . $css_class . '"><span class="attribute-label c1">' . $attribute_label . ':</span> <span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $attribute_value) . '</span></div>';

                $counter++;
            }
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div></div>';

    if ($products->max_num_pages > 1) {
        // Output the AJAX pagination links

        $pagination_args = array(
            'base' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '?action=load_products_ajax&paged=%#%',
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $page,
            'total' => $products->max_num_pages,
            'prev_text' => '<< Zurück',
            'next_text' => 'Weiter >>',
            'mid_size' => 5, // Number of links to display on each side of the current page
        );

        echo '<div class="pagination2255 paginationtop">';
        echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
        echo '</div>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No products found.';
}

wp_reset_postdata();

$output = ob_get_clean(); // Get the buffered output
echo $output;

wp_die(); // End the AJAX request
 }
 add_action('wp_ajax_load_products_ajax', 'load_products_ajax_callback');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_products_ajax', 'load_products_ajax_callback'); // Allow non-logged-in users to use the AJAX endpoint
```

custom-ajax.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   // Define a variable to keep track of the current page
   var currentPage = 1;

  // Function to handle the AJAX request and update the product list
 function loadProducts(page) {
    // Fetch the product list from the server using JavaScript Fetch API
fetch(twentytwentyone_ajax_object.ajax_url + '?action=load_products_ajax&paged=' + page)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // Update the product list with the new content
    $('#product-list-container').html(response);
    // Update the current page
    currentPage = page;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error if necessary
  });
   }

    // Initial loading of products (page 1)
 loadProducts(1);

 // Handle click on pagination links
 $(document).on('click', '.pagination-link', function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
var page = parseInt($(this).attr('data-page'));
// Load products for the clicked page
loadProducts(page);
 });
});
```

template-home.php:

```
<div id="content2255inner">

<!-- Product Display -->
<div id="product-list-container">
    <?php
    $paged = max(1, (int) get_query_var('page')); // Ensure the current page is at least 1

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 22,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'title', // Sort by product name
        'order' => 'ASC',    // Order in ascending (A to Z)
    );

    $products = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($products->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="table-2255"><div class="table-thead-2255"><div class="table-tr-2255"></div></div><div class="table-tbody-2255">';

        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();
            global $product;

            // Get the product data
            $product_name = $product->get_name();
            $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            $product_permalink = get_permalink();

            echo '<div class="table-tr-2255">';
            echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entryImage"><img src="' . $product_image[0] . '" alt="' . $product_name . '"></div>';
            echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entryName"><h2 class="c1"><a class="c1" href="' . $product_permalink . '">' . $product_name . '</a></h2></div>';

            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            if ($attributes && !empty($attributes)) { // Add a check for $attributes
                $counter = 1;
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($attribute->get_name());
                    $attribute_value = array();

                    // Get attribute options as labels
                    $options = $attribute->get_terms();
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        $attribute_value[] = $option->name;
                    }

                    $css_class = 'entry' . $counter;

                    echo '<div class="table-td-2255 ' . $css_class . '"><span class="attribute-label c1">' . $attribute_label . ':</span> <span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $attribute_value) . '</span></div>';

                    $counter++;
                }
            }

            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div></div>';

        if ($products->max_num_pages > 1) {
            // Output the AJAX pagination links
            $pagination_args = array(
                'base' => add_query_arg('paged', '%#%'), // Use the current page URL with the addition of the 'paged' query parameter
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => $paged,
                'total' => $products->max_num_pages,
                'prev_text' => '<< Zurück',
                'next_text' => 'Weiter >>',
                'mid_size' => 5, // Number of links to display on each side of the current page
            );

            echo '<div class="pagination2255 paginationtop">';
            echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No products found.';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried stopPropagation also when you write out the links HTML are you suing href of # or void() and using the on click event to do the pagination update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `template-home.php` you query the first page of 22 products and in your JavaScript code you load again the same products (page 1) via Ajax. So you need to choose on the first load if your products are displayed by the template or loaded via Ajax, and you choose to load page 1 via Ajax, your template file will be nearly empty (with some few HTML tags).

There are some mistakes in your code:

- In the JS enqueue part, a `/` was missing in the URL, so the JavaScript was not enqueued by WordPress and there was not any Ajax call.
- In the JavaScript file, `$(this).attr('data-page')` was not getting the selected page number.
- IN the PHP Ajax receiver function, `$_POST['page']` was always null, so `max(1, (int)$_POST['page'])` was always giving `1`.

In the code below, I have chosen, on the initial load, to display the products via the template.

In `functions.php` file:

```php
// Enqueue scripts and localize variables for AJAX pagination
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_ajax_pagination_scripts'); 
function enqueue_ajax_pagination_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'ajax-pagination-script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom-ajax.js', // For child themes use: get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
        array('jquery'), '1.0', true
    );
    
    // Localize variables to be used in the AJAX script
    wp_localize_script(
        'ajax-pagination-script', 
        'twentytwentyone_ajax_object', 
        array( 
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        )
    );
} 

// Get product html output
function product_query_outyput_html( $paged = 1 ) {
    // the WP Query
    $products = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 22,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'orderby' => 'title', // Sort by product name
        'order' => 'ASC',    // Order in ascending (A to Z) 
    ));

    ob_start(); // Start buffering output

    if ($products->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="table-2255"><div class="table-thead-2255"><div class="table-tr-2255"></div></div><div class="table-tbody-2255">';

        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();
            global $product;

            // Get the product data
            $product_name = $product->get_name();
            $product_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
            $product_permalink = get_permalink();

            // Output the product details
            echo '<div class="table-tr-2255">';
            echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entryImage"><img src="' . $product_image[0] . '" alt="' . $product_name . '"></div>';
            echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entryName"><h2 class="c1"><a class="c1" href="' . $product_permalink . '">' . $product_name . '</a></h2></div>';

            // Additional product attributes
            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            if ($attributes && !empty($attributes)) { // Add a check for $attributes
                $counter = 1;
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($attribute->get_name());
                    $attribute_value = array();
                    $options = $attribute->get_terms(); // Get attribute options as labels
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        $attribute_value[] = $option->name;
                    }
                    echo '<div class="table-td-2255 entry' . $counter . '"><span class="attribute-label c1">' . $attribute_label . ':</span> <span class="attribute-value">' . implode(', ', $attribute_value) . '</span></div>';
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div></div>';

        if ($products->max_num_pages > 1) {
            // Output the AJAX pagination links
            $pagination_args = array(
                'base' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '?action=load_products_ajax&paged=%#%',
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => $paged,
                'total' => $products->max_num_pages,
                'prev_text' => '<< Zurück',
                'next_text' => 'Weiter >>',
                'mid_size' => 5, // Number of links to display on each side of the current page
            );
            echo '<div class="pagination2255 paginationtop">';
            echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No products found.';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean(); // display the buffered content 
}
    
// Callback function for AJAX pagination
add_action('wp_ajax_load_products_ajax', 'load_products_ajax_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_products_ajax', 'load_products_ajax_callback');
function load_products_ajax_callback() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['paged']) && $_REQUEST['paged'] > 0) {
        $paged = max(1, (int) $_REQUEST['paged']); // Ensure the current page is at least 1

        echo product_query_outyput_html( $paged );
    }
    wp_die(); // End the AJAX request
}
```

In `template-home.php` file:

```php
<div id="content2255inner">
    <!-- Product Display -->
    <div id="product-list-container">
        <?php echo product_query_outyput_html(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `custom-ajax.js` file:

```php
jQuery(function ($){
    // Fuction to get the query string parameters
    function getParams(url) {
        var params = {};
        const match = url.match(/\?(.*)$/);
    
        if (match && match[1]) {
            match[1].split('&').forEach(function (pair) {
                pair = pair.split('=');
                params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            });
        }
        return params;
    };

    // Function to handle the AJAX request and update the product list
    function loadProducts(page) {
        // Fetch the product list from the server using JavaScript Fetch API
        fetch(twentytwentyone_ajax_object.ajax_url + '?action=load_products_ajax&paged=' + page)
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                // Update the product list with the new content
                $('#product-list-container').html(response);
                // Update the current page
                currentPage = page;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // Handle error if necessary
            });
    }
    
    // var currentPage = 1; // Define a variable to keep track of the current page
    // loadProducts(currentPage); // Initial loading of products (current page 1)

    // Handle click on pagination links
    $(document.body).on('click', 'a.page-numbers', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
        var page = parseInt(getParams($(this).attr('href'))['paged']); // Get "paged" query var value
        loadProducts(page); // Load products for the clicked page
    });
});
```

Now Ajax is correctly enabled so everything works.